# Font-face working on local but not on server

Tags: html, css, server, font-face, local

like the title say font-face is not working on internet but it's working on local, I don't understand why. Can someone help me ?
Here's my code:

`@font-face {
    font-family: 'ocraextended';
    src: url('font/OCRAEXT.ttf')  format('truetype');
}`

Comment: Is there any error in the Google/Firefox developer console ? Check the network tab on the developer console to know the HTTP status code of your font loading, or post a screen of the tab if you are not familiar with it. Or simply, post the url of your website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have installed the font on your PC or Mac it would display in your browser but not on systems where it's not installed. You will have to upload the different font files with your webpage and refer to these font files in the css.

Example:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('font/OCRAEXT.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('font/OCRAEXT.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('font/OCRAEXT.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('font/OCRAEXT.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('font/OCRAEXT.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('font/OCRAEXT.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

**Another option** is to use Google fonts. It is free and easy to use (cross browser compatible without lots of files and font formats):

In HTML

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Overpass+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
```

**or**
In CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Overpass+Mono');
```

Then you make a html element use the font like this:

```
h1 {font-family: 'Overpass Mono', monospace;}
```

PS: Mono spaced fonts are originally made to be machine readable. It's not  the best human readable fonts. But hey, you know best what fits your design.